# Require_once fails after hours of running php and php-fpm requires a restart

Tags: php

We have a strange issue that has started happening on one of our servers.

After about 24 hours an initial script that has a `require_once` in it suddenly starts failing.

It may not fail every time. as we use the same script to load images it may be that 3 or 4 random images would fail every time the page loads.

I've added the script and the error although there is no errors until about 24 hours after php fpm has started so please don't try and debug the code:

```bash
gareth@app8 /var/log/nginx % php -v
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2020 07:24:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

gareth@app8 /var/log/nginx % nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.17.8
```

```bash
2020/03/05 04:24:38 [error] 37086#37086: *249519 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../system/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/mindworks.co.uk/public_html/bootstrap.php on line 12" while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.89.232, server: mindworks.co.uk, request: "GET /$
```

```php
<?php

/**
 * must define URL_ROOT in here for resources
 * to be loaded in correctly, this has moved out
 * of Config.
 */
define('URL_ROOT', '/');

/**
 * load the system's bootstrap.
 */
require_once '../system/bootstrap.php';
```

Comment: Hello. The version may help in later debugging. However can you also post to your question the source code pertaining to the problem description *we use the same script to load images it may be that 3 or 4 random images would fail every time the page loads*? .... If that's not possible (to share the source code) then it seems that the problem itself is periodic as you say, and as such, might involve how images are getting onto the server in the first place. Is that too periodic on a similar interval?

Comment: It appears that you are using a *relative path* to get at `bootstrap.php`. As such, have you tracked down all instances in which you call the script (that you do post) as it relates to *it may not fail every time. as we use the same script to load images*? If you call the script you do post for example from another script higher up or down from `../` it will fail, because you have a relative path requirement. For example, suppose the script you do post is called `needed.php`. Where is `needed.php` called in your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion that has helped me with symlink deployments of code is to set `opcache.revalidate_path` to `On` in `/etc/php.ini`:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/php.ini
```

And then go to the bottom and add something like this:

```ini
[PHP]
opcache.revalidate_path = On;
```

As explained in the official PHP manual for [`opcache.revalidate-path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.revalidate-path):

> If disabled, existing cached files using the same `include_path` will be reused. Thus, if a file with the same name is elsewhere in the `include_path`, it won't be found.